# What does C20019 IN PAIRS AT 900 MAX CTS WITH 2 ROWS OF BRIDGING AT 1/3 POINTS mean in a technical drawing?

Tags: civil-engineering, technical-drawing

Specifically, does in pairs mean that there are 2 C20019 members per indicated line on a technical drawing?

Comment: Well you get pairs of shoes ... So, give us all a chance and show the drawing...

Comment: CTS might be an abbreviation for "cut to size" - but we need the drawing for some context, to answer the question.

Comment: I suggest that it is C2109 in pairs at 900 max centres